# How to pivot duplicate rows to distinct columns in excel

Tags: powerquery

I have an excel data where I need to transpose the duplicate rows to columns suitable for analysis. Please let me know how to do this?

For example,

My excel data looks like

```
id    metrics    date       value
1       A        20190812   100
1       A        20190813   100
1       A        20190814   100
1       B        20190812   200
1       B        20190813   130
2       A        20190812   100
2       B        20190813   106
2       C        20190814   104
```

The result I look forward to is

```
id   A    B    C    date
1   100  200  null  20190812
1   100  130  null  20190813
1   100  null null  20190814
2   100  null null  20190812
2   null 106  null  20190813
2   null null 104   20190814
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below in **Pivot**:

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]
  Pivot =
    Table.Pivot(
      Source,
      List.Distinct(Source[metrics]),
      "metrics",
      "value",
      List.Sum)
in
  Pivot
```

Comment: I gave a quick edit to clean up the code posted, formatting it, and making it a full query, rather than a snippet. This can now be copy-pasted into Power Query's Advanced Editor view.